# How to tell IDEA/Studio that the null check has been done?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm developing with Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA.

I have enabled the inspection check called "Constant conditions & exceptions" that shows a warning if I am risking a NPE, such as:

```java
String foo = foo.bar(); // Foo#bar() is @nullable
if (foo.contains("bar")) { // I'm living dangerously
    ...
}
```

I have the following in my code:

```java
String encoding = contentEncoding == null ? null : contentEncoding.getValue();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encoding) && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(entity.getContent());
} else {
    inputStream = entity.getContent();
}
```

Here's the source code of `TextUtils#isEmpty(String)`:

```java
/**
 * Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.
 * @param str the string to be examined
 * @return true if str is null or zero length
 */
public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I'm not risking any NPE because `TextUtils#isEmpty(String)` would return true to a `null` pointer.

However I'm still getting the little `Method invocation 'encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'` warning, which can be annoying.

Is it possible to make this check smarter and ignore the NPE warning if there's already a null-check done?

Comment: You could circumvent this by typing `"gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(encoding)` instead.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but it's not always `String#equals`. For example `foo.contains(bar)`, both being pointers: it can warn about foo being nullable, while the null check has already been done by `TextUtils#isEmpty`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can look into the link that Peter Gromov mention in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315428/1350762).

Created some simple classes that resemble your setup:

A class with a method annotated with `@Nullable`:

[image]

The `TextUtil` class with it's `isEmpty` method:

[image]

And finally the main class calling the `TextUtil#isEmpty`:

[image]

Now if you enter the `File -> Settings...` and go to `Inspections ->Constant conditions & exceptions` part you can change the `Configure Assert/Check Methods` to cater for your `isEmpty` method:

[image]

Add a new `IsNull` check method:

[image]

Enter the `TextUtil` class, `isEmpty` method and `CharSequence` parameter:

[image]

This gives this `Assert/Check Method Configuration` window:

[image]

Press `Ok` and then `Ok` again to go back to the editor view and you'll see that the inspection disappeared:

[image]

You are actually telling IntelliJ that the `isEmpty` method is doing a null check on the `str` parameter.

Comment: Woaw. Thanks for the effort you put into this answer. Awesome!

Comment: Seems like there is no such option (Configure Assert/Check Methods) at least in Android Studio 1.2.2

Comment: @maba do you know how to do it in last Android Studio?

Comment: @tse No I don't know that. I am only using the vanilla IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, not the Android Studio.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `//noinspection ConstantConditions` that will remove the NPE warning for the following line, like this:

```java
String encoding = contentEncoding == null ? null : contentEncoding.getValue();

//noinspection ConstantConditions
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encoding) && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(entity.getContent());
} else {
    inputStream = entity.getContent();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` annotation.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int indexViewType) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    }
    ItemViewProvider provider = getProviderByIndex(indexViewType);
    provider.adapter = MultiTypeAdapter.this;
    return provider.onCreateViewHolder(inflater, parent);
}
```

Comment: Don't suppress it on a wide range of code like this: 1) there's no way to tell what you're actually suppressing (can `provider` be null, or `parent`, or `inflater`, ...?); 2) it disables checks for any future code in that range (even an explicit `((Object) null).toString();` will not warn about the null-access, if added to this method)

Answer (score 3):

1. Select "TextUtils.isEmpty".
2. Right Click -> Show Context Actions -> Add Method Contract.
3. Enter "null -> true".
4. Save the configuration xml.

Please check the details [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html#syntax)

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-check-assert-methods.html for IDEA 12.
In IDEA 13 EAP, you can add method contract: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93372

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately marked as "right answer" solution is of date. But I found equivalent for me solution.

The new versions of IDE work correctly with static methods. So the example from the question won't throw warning anymore.

```
TextUtils#isEmpty(String);

public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
    // your checks
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it throws warning for android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(String)