# How to tell Android Studio that there is no NullPointerException risk in this statement?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position < getItemCount()) {
        holder.bind(mServiceInfo.agencies.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mServiceInfo != null && mServiceInfo.agencies != null ? mServiceInfo.agencies.size() : 0;
}
```

Android Studio warns me in the `onBindViewHolder` method, saying that my `mServiceInfo.agencies.get` call might raise a NPE.

There is no way this can happen, because `position` is always a positive integer. I've even changed the test condition to: `position >= 0 && position < getItemCount()` but the warning is still shown.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of warning in IDE window]

How can I configure the IDE not to raise a warning here?

Please note that:

- I don't want to disable the lint check or disable it for this statement. I know that lint checks can be disabled, that's not the point of my question here. Also, I like to avoid disabling checks because in maintenance the code can be changed and the comment asking the IDE not to care about one check may remain, which would cause undesired/unexpected behavior.
- Apart from concurrency, there is no condition which would cause an NPE in the `onBindViewHolder`, so the IDE warning is not valid here
- I do care about warnings, especially when it's about checking NPEs, because they can easily show where I did wrong and avoid a possible bug. Warnings are very important and I tend to have zero warnings when compiling, especially about when they detect possible bugs.
- It is possible to change how the IDE behaves vs. NPE, [this kind of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19319326/334493) is exactly what I had in mind when posting this question

Comment: Why are you so concerned with a warning? It is not an error.

Comment: It is saying you may get a null value from that container, does not have anything to do with your position value

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi: I like clean code and clean IDE status

Comment: @Dummy: if either `mServiceInfo` or `mServiceInfo.agencies` is null, `getItemCount()` will return 0. `position` is a positive integer, so `position < getItemCount()` will never be true if there is a null object.

Comment: As @DavidMedenjak suggested, instruct Lint not to bore you anymore.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi: I know how to disable a lint check for a statement, I wanted the IDE to figure this on its own.

Comment: Then rewrite the IDE. Even if I think it's actually correct.

Comment: If either mServiceInfo or mServiceInfo.agencies is null, you will get a null pointer exception on them unless your implementation returns 0 when they are null

Comment: @Dummy: the implementation is in the question. It does return 0 if either is null.

Comment: You are not showing us enough code to make the determination that neither `mServiceInfo` nor `mServiceInfo.agencies` can never be `null`. For all we know Android Studio's warning is entirely valid (eg think of what can happen under concurrent access)

Comment: They can be null, but `getItemCount` handles their nullity.

Comment: See my comment edit. You could have a [TOCTTOU problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) when a concurrent thread does make one of them `null`.

Comment: Please show me a combination of `position`, `mServiceInfo` and `mServiceInfo.agencies` that will raise a NPE in `onBindViewHolder`. There is none.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the first valid point. Fair enough, I didn't think about concurrency. Thanks.

Comment: Sure there is: Thread1 calls `getItemCount` which returns 1, Thread2 then makes `mServiceInfo` or `mServiceInfo.agencies` `null`, Thread1 dereferences them and gets a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You haven't mentioned concurrency when I wrote that comment. Concurrency is a very valid point in this case. But I'm sure the IDE wouldn't remove the warning if my code was synchronized to ensure that no thread can touch either object between the two calls. So my question remains.

Answer (score 2):

The warning occurs because the static analysis of your code says one of the fields may be `null`. This is either because of accessed fields not set in the constructor, `@Nullable` annotations, or some other static analysis things.

First, be sure you are handling the NPE and that it can not occur. The warning is there for a reason. If you checked that, you have 4 options:

- Actually do a `null` check
- Refactor your code, remove `@Nullable`, always initialize the field
- Disable the lint check completely, or
- Disable the check just for some parts

I recommentd the last option, since it will also work with version control systems and other work stations. (If you are sure that you know what you are doing.)

1. Press `Alt`+`Enter`
2. Select `Inspection 'Constant Conditions & Exceptions' options`
3. Chose your option.

You will see a preview of how far the annotation will reach, usually a single comment for the statement will suffice:

[image]

This will add the following comment above, which you could also add manually:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

Comment: That's rather a workaround, I'd rather have the IDE understand that the statement wouldn't raise any NPE

Comment: The IDE / lint is actually checking your code. If you have some `@Nullable` annotated code it will raise this warning if not checking the result. Also if you don't initialize your fields in every possible path, and more. The only options you have is rewrite your code, add a null check or suppress the warning.