# Android studio highlights an area, without any errors in the code

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android studio. I just added `setOnItemSelectedListener` for a `Spinner` and the background color of the code for listener turns brown (somehow like a selection):

[image]

What does this color mean?
Is it normal or is it indicating a problem?
And how can I make it go away because its really annoying.

Comment: i think these color shows null pointer exception in this code. check code for any missing .

Comment: that color tells you that you could improve that code but it would still run. when you keep the mouse over it, what does the box say?

Comment: This seems like autogenerated block of code. Does typing anything in it remove it or it just stays there forever? :D Hover above it to see what the warning's all about..?

Comment: @JoãoSardinha it says that **Method invocation sp.... may produce java.lang.NullPointerException** but why?

Comment: @Vucko it stays there

Comment: it is the default code, not written anything yet, what can be possibly be the cause of null pointer exception?

Comment: becasue maybe you havent done the "sp = (Spinner)findViewById...", if you have that you can click "ignore issue" or something long those lines

Comment: this code is followed by `final Spinner sp = ((Spinner) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(ids[i], "id", getPackageName())));`

Comment: Wild guess but I think variable `sp` can be null. Use `if(sp != null)` before setting the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the Android Studio trying to warn you that some method invocation may produce some exception (usually a `NullPointerException`). You can fix this by adding an `if` check for each thing like:

```
if(myThing != null){
    //do stuff
}
```

Or simply by adding before using `myThing`:

```
assert myThing != null;
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371938/proper-way-to-handle-android-studios-nullpointerexception-lint-warning) and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302211/how-to-tell-idea-studio-that-the-null-check-has-been-done) question for further improving your insight on this.

Comment: and myThins is?? is it the spinner?

Comment: It's anything. In your case a Spinner. It can be a Button, TextView, literally anything.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, this thing annoys me as well sometimes. If you find a way to improve my post, feel free to edit it.

Comment: Sure. but the answer seems to be complete although it is short.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the theme you can do it by `File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->` In scheme name select `Default` and apply to see the white background of the studio.

Comment: It is not about theme, it is about an area being highlighted by the editor

Comment: Since this is answering another question, I don't think this answer is very helpful here.