# TextUtils.isEmpty checks for null but lint doesn't recognise

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

In the Android studio whenever I proceed with `TextUtils.isEmpty` check, the lint shows the argument might be null. It doesn't make sense as `isEmpty` will check for nullability.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue without using asserts.

P.S. `ImageUtils.getWidth` accepts aspectRatio as null hence no lint warning there.

Comment: maybe your dynamicImageUrl is always null

Comment: I think this broke recently in Android Studio. I remember that TextUtils.isEmpty() was considered a null check until recently, and the timestamp on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652618/324625) implies that was the case.